# Boxing Count-up / delay / timer

Tags: swift, swift3, delay

I created a boxing simulation and am now going back to add in animations.  Now, I am adding a "Ref's Countup" to add suspense.  I have tried numerous things, but none have gotten what I want.  I tried the:

```
Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 1)
knockdownNumber.text = "\(knockdownNumberInt)"
```

and

```
sleep(1)
knockdownNumber.text = "\(knockdownNumberInt)"
```

Those paused the UI.  So they did wait for the appropriate ammount of time, but did not change my text.
Then there are these which all only counted once (ie. 1, 3 or 1, 8).

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
        self.knockdownNumber.text = "\(self.knockdownNumberInt)"
    }
```

and

```
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: false) { (timer) in
        self.knockdownNumber.text = "\(self.knockdownNumberInt)"
    }
```

and

```
 delay(1) {
        self.knockdownNumber.text = "\(self.knockdownNumberInt)"
    }
```

with the delay function as

```
 func delay(_ delay:Double, closure:@escaping ()->()) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(
        deadline: DispatchTime.now() + Double(Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC), execute: closure)
}
```

The way I call the function (which these are all in) is after he gets knockdown.  This code looks like this.

```
knockdownNumber.text = "1"
    knockdownNumberInt = 1
    downSec()
    knockdownNumberInt = knockdownNumberInt + 1
    downSec()
    knockdownNumberInt = knockdownNumberInt + 1
    downSec()
    if fighter2.endurance < 400 {
        knockdownNumberInt = knockdownNumberInt + 1
        downSec()
    }
    if fighter2.endurance < 300 {
        knockdownNumberInt = knockdownNumberInt + 1
        downSec()
    }
    if fighter2.endurance < 200 {
        knockdownNumberInt = knockdownNumberInt + 1
        downSec()
    }
    if fighter2.endurance < 100 {
        knockdownNumberInt = knockdownNumberInt + 1
        downSec()
    }
    if fighter2.endurance < 0 {
        knockdownNumberInt = knockdownNumberInt + 1
        downSec()
    }
    if fighter2.endurance < -100 {
        knockdownNumberInt = knockdownNumberInt + 1
        downSec()
    }
```

I am truly stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are nearly there with this approach:

```
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: false) { (timer) in
    self.knockdownNumber.text = "\(self.knockdownNumberInt)"
}
```

All you need to do is set `repeats` to `true` and the timer will repeat forever.

Now we need to decide when to stop the timer. We should decide this before we even started the timer, instead of doing what you did - decrementing the `knockdownNumberInt` while starting new times. This does not work because the stuff you put in the timer's closure is asynchronous.

So we decide what number we are counting up to:

```
knockdownNumber.text = "1"
knockdownNumberInt = 3
if fighter2.endurance < 400 {
    knockdownNumberInt += 1 // use the "+=" to make it cleaner!
}
if fighter2.endurance < 300 {
    knockdownNumberInt += 1
}
if fighter2.endurance < 200 {
    knockdownNumberInt += 1
}
if fighter2.endurance < 100 {
    knockdownNumberInt += 1
}
if fighter2.endurance < 0 {
    knockdownNumberInt += 1
}
if fighter2.endurance < -100 {
    knockdownNumberInt += 1
}
```

Declare a property called `currentCountDown` in the class:

```
var currentCountDown = 1
```

Then you can create your timer like this:

```
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { [weak self] (timer) in
    guard let `self` = self else { // I added this to prevent a retain cycle.
         timer.invalidate()
         return
    }
    self.currentCountDown += 1
    self.knockdownNumber.text = "\(self.currentCountDown)"
    if self.currentCountDown == self.knockdownNumberInt {
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}
```

Comment: the one problem with this is it does not pause the code until the count is done.  Is there way to do that as well?

Comment: @Peter it should do. I called `timer.invalidate`

Comment: There is one more problem.  If you hit the skip count button, and another guy gets knocked down, the count goes forever.  Is there a way to cancel the count from the skip button?  Thanks, Peter

Comment: @Peter make `timer` a class level variable. Then call `timer.invalidate`